# Anne Boleyn had a brother called Tenpin

Tags: pronunciation, colloquialisms, jokes

> Anne Boleyn had a brother called Tenpin

Can someone explain this joke? It probably has some sort of colloquial meaning I'm missing or some way of pronunciation that makes it funny.
I've found this joke being performed by British comedians and also on some obscure websites.

Comment: Ten...pin...Boleyn: [Ten-pin bowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-pin_bowling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His full name would be "Tenpin Boleyn", as in ten pin bowling

Comment: Ah, Boleyn is pronounced like bowlin' ?

Comment: There are several pronunciations of *Boleyn*. One of them sounds like *bowlin'*.

Comment: I would say that the most common US pronunciation of *Boleyn* is *bowlin'* (with the accent on "bow").

Comment: In my neck of the woods, it's boLIN.

Comment: *Boleyn* was a French surname (pronounced Bo-linn in English), the gentry family from whence Anne came having been Normans. They were a Norfolk family with their seat at Blickling (today a magnificent National Trust property). But the Anglicised form of the name, which you can see on one jeweller's shop in Norwich is *Bullen*. *Bullens* the jewellers are, I gather, descendants of the *Boleyns*.